# How to manage multiple segues?

Tags: ios, objective-c, iphone, segue, uistoryboardsegue

I have a ViewController  which has two segues and I want that segue to present viewcontroller after fetching data from URL. So I have kept `preparesegueWithIdentifier` in `connectionDidFinishLoading` method.

But I am able to show only first viewcontroller.

I want that both segues works properly.

```
 #import "specialistquery.h"
    #import "FitnessView.h"
    #import "askCall.h"
    #import "Header.h"

@interface specialistquery ()<UITextFieldDelegate,UITextViewDelegate>
{
    NSMutableData *responseData;
    UIAlertView *alert;


}


@end

@implementation specialistquery
@synthesize title,discription,title1,CallBackBtn,SubmitBtn;


- (void)viewDidLoad {
    [super viewDidLoad];
    // Do any additional setup after loading the view.



    dataArray = [[NSArray alloc]initWithObjects:@"Yoga Specialist", @"Dietician", @"Fitness Specialist", @"Homeopathic", @"Ayurvedic Specialist", nil];

    UIPickerView *picker = [[UIPickerView alloc]init];
    picker.delegate=self;
    picker.dataSource=self;
    [picker setShowsSelectionIndicator:YES];
    [self.selectspecs setInputView:picker];



    //toolbar
    UIToolbar *toolbar=[[UIToolbar alloc]initWithFrame:CGRectMake(0, 0, 320, 30)];
    [toolbar setTintColor:[UIColor grayColor]];
    UIBarButtonItem *doneBtn=[[UIBarButtonItem alloc]initWithTitle:@"Done" style:UIBarButtonItemStylePlain target:self action:@selector(showSelectedDate)];
    UIBarButtonItem *space=[[UIBarButtonItem alloc]initWithBarButtonSystemItem:UIBarButtonSystemItemFlexibleSpace target:nil action:nil];
    [toolbar setItems:[NSArray arrayWithObjects: space, doneBtn,nil]];
    [self.selectspecs setInputAccessoryView:toolbar];
    [self.title1 setInputAccessoryView:toolbar];
    [self.discription setInputAccessoryView:toolbar];

}

-(void)showSelectedDate
{
    [self.selectspecs resignFirstResponder];
    [self.title1 resignFirstResponder];
}

- (void)prepareForSegue:(UIStoryboardSegue *)segue sender:(id)sender
{
    if ([segue.identifier isEqualToString:@"good"]) {
        FitnessView *spec = [segue destinationViewController];
        spec.str = _selectspecs.text;
    }

    if ([segue.identifier isEqualToString:@"callback"]) {
        askCall *spec = [segue destinationViewController];
        spec.str = _selectspecs.text;
    }

}


- (NSInteger)numberOfComponentsInPickerView:(UIPickerView *)pickerView
{
    return 1;
}

- (NSInteger)pickerView:(UIPickerView *)pickerView numberOfRowsInComponent:(NSInteger)component
{
    return [dataArray count];
}

- (NSString *)pickerView:(UIPickerView *)pickerView titleForRow:(NSInteger)row forComponent:(NSInteger)component
{
    return [dataArray objectAtIndex:row];
}

- (void)pickerView:(UIPickerView *)pickerView didSelectRow:(NSInteger)row inComponent:(NSInteger)component
{
    self.selectspecs.text = [dataArray objectAtIndex:row];

}


- (IBAction)DisKey:(id)sender {

    [self.selectspecs resignFirstResponder];
    [self.title1 resignFirstResponder];
    [self.discription resignFirstResponder];

}


-(BOOL)shouldPerformSegueWithIdentifier:(NSString *)identifier sender:(id)sender
{
    if ([identifier isEqualToString:@"good"])
    {
         if ([title1.text isEqualToString:@""] || [discription.text isEqualToString:@""] || [_selectspecs.text isEqualToString:@""])
         {
             UIAlertView *alert = [[UIAlertView alloc] initWithTitle:@"Oppss!!!" message:@"ALL FIELDS MUST BE FILLED" delegate:self cancelButtonTitle:@"OK" otherButtonTitles:nil, nil ];
             [alert show];
             return NO;
        }

        else
        {
            NSDate *todayDate = [NSDate date]; // get today date
            NSDateFormatter *dateFormatter = [[NSDateFormatter alloc] init]; // here we create NSDateFormatter object for change the Format of date..
            [dateFormatter setDateFormat:@"dd-MM-yyyy"]; //Here we can set the format which we need
            NSString *convertedDateString = [dateFormatter stringFromDate:todayDate];// here convert date in
            NSString *url;

            url=@"http://www.bha.com/mDru/index.php";
            const char *bytes = [[NSString stringWithFormat:@"question=%@&description=%@&createddate=%@&createdby=iPhone&userid=519&tag=storequestion",title1.text,discription.text,convertedDateString ] UTF8String];
            NSURL *url1 = [NSURL URLWithString:url];
            NSMutableURLRequest *request = [NSMutableURLRequest requestWithURL:url1];

            [request setHTTPMethod:@"POST"];
            [request setHTTPBody:[NSData dataWithBytes:bytes length:strlen(bytes)]];
            [[NSURLConnection alloc] initWithRequest:request delegate:self];


        }
    }


    else if ([identifier isEqualToString:@"callback"])
    {
        if ([title1.text isEqualToString:@""] || [discription.text isEqualToString:@""] || [_selectspecs.text isEqualToString:@""])
        {
            UIAlertView *alert = [[UIAlertView alloc] initWithTitle:@"Oppss!!!" message:@"ALL FIELDS MUST BE FILLED" delegate:self cancelButtonTitle:@"OK" otherButtonTitles:nil, nil ];
            [alert show];
            return NO;
        }

        else
        {
            NSDate *todayDate = [NSDate date]; // get today date
            NSDateFormatter *dateFormatter = [[NSDateFormatter alloc] init]; // here we create NSDateFormatter object for change the Format of date..
            [dateFormatter setDateFormat:@"dd-MM-yyyy"]; //Here we can set the format which we need
            NSString *convertedDateString = [dateFormatter stringFromDate:todayDate];// here convert date in
            NSString *url;

            url=@"http://www.bha.com/mDru/index.php";
            const char *bytes = [[NSString stringWithFormat:@"question=%@&description=%@&createddate=%@&createdby=iPhone&userid=519&tag=storequestion",title1.text,discription.text,convertedDateString ] UTF8String];
            NSURL *url1 = [NSURL URLWithString:url];
            NSMutableURLRequest *request = [NSMutableURLRequest requestWithURL:url1];

            [request setHTTPMethod:@"POST"];
            [request setHTTPBody:[NSData dataWithBytes:bytes length:strlen(bytes)]];
            [[NSURLConnection alloc] initWithRequest:request delegate:self];


        }

    }


    return NO;
}




-(void)connection:(NSURLConnection *)connection didReceiveResponse:(NSURLResponse *)response
{
    responseData = [[NSMutableData alloc] init];


    alert = [[UIAlertView alloc] initWithTitle:@"Please Wait..." message:@"Saving Data" delegate:self cancelButtonTitle:nil otherButtonTitles: nil];
    [alert show];

}
- (void)connection:(NSURLConnection *)connection didReceiveData:(NSData *)data {
    [responseData appendData:data];
}
- (void)connection:(NSURLConnection *)connection didFailWithError:(NSError *)error
{
    [alert dismissWithClickedButtonIndex:0 animated:YES];

    UIAlertView *nsjsdn = [[UIAlertView alloc] initWithTitle:nil message:@"Internet connection problem" delegate:self cancelButtonTitle:@"Exit" otherButtonTitles:nil, nil];
    [nsjsdn show];

}
- (void)connectionDidFinishLoading:(NSURLConnection *)connection {

    NSString *teststr=[[NSString alloc]  initWithData:responseData encoding:NSUTF8StringEncoding];

    NSString *str1234 = [teststr stringByTrimmingCharactersInSet:[NSCharacterSet newlineCharacterSet]];
    NSLog(@"Response is %@ %lul",str1234,(unsigned long)
          [str1234 length]);


    [alert dismissWithClickedButtonIndex:0 animated:YES];


    [self performSegueWithIdentifier:@"good" sender:self];

    [self performSegueWithIdentifier:@"callback" sender:self];

}

@end
```

Comment: What would it even mean for both segues to trigger?  What kind of UI are you designing?

Comment: As @Avi mentioned why do you want to navigate to two viewcontrollers at the same time? It's wrong

Comment: you should know that the delegate method `shouldPerformSegueWithIdentifier :` is only called if the segue is initiated from UI itself, meaning a segue link in IB, because view control assumes that when you call `performSegue` you know what you're doing and therefore skips this part. Just wanted to point out.

Comment: @DilumN I want to segue only one view at a time but after fetching data. both buttons have different segue and different view but functionality is same. I also tried if-else in connection did finish loading but it prompt an error " undeclare identifier 'identifier'.

Comment: @M.Porooshani I already initated segue from IB, but i want to segue after completion of data fetching.

Comment: You have to perform segue for only one viewcontroller at a time. Fromt he comment 'both buttons have different segue and different view but functionality is same' then why are performing segue for both the view

Comment: @BalajiKondalrayal because they further have different tasks, after segue to there corresponding views

Comment: Yes thats ok. But you have to performsegue for the view where you want to move.

Comment: @BalajiKondalrayal I am able to segue with my above coding but i am facing an issue i.e., when i click on any one of button, both segue to that view which is written first on connectionDidfinishloading . Check out code first.

Comment: I don't understand what you're trying to do ? please explain more. 
You can't call performSegueWithIdentifier twice from the same view at the same time only `[self performSegueWithIdentifier:@"good" sender:self];` will get called.

Comment: @enzo yes dear, that what i am saying.Now I want that if first button is clicked identifier "good" get called and when second button is clicked identifier "callback" get called . BUT AFTER COMPLETING DATA FETCHING FROM URL.

Comment: You have two buttons right? You need only perform one segue depending on the button pressed right? Set the property 'selected' of the button on button click and check which button's 'selected' property is set and call that segue.

Comment: Hope I understood what you were trying to do..

Comment: @MeharoofNajeeb As I mentioned on top, I want segue after my data fetching completed. I want Something in connectiondidfinishloading

Comment: Thats what I asked you to do... Set the button's 'selected' property to 'YES' in the IBAction and check which button's 'selected' property is set to 'YES' in connectionDidFinishLoading method and call associated segue.

Comment: @MeharoofNajeeb  can you please send coding by taking reference of my coding.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you do this, I believe you should get the result you require.

Make IBOutlets button1 and button2 for your buttons and IBAction methods for your buttons and set its selected property to YES.

```
- (IBAction)button1Clicked:(id)sender
{
    button1.selected = YES;
    if (button2.selected)
    {
        // This is done so that both buttons do not appear as clicked at the same time
        button2.selected = NO;
    }
}

- (IBAction)button2Clicked:(id)sender
{
    button2.selected = YES;
    if (button1.selected)
    {
        // This is done so that both buttons do not appear as clicked at the same time
        button1.selected = NO;
    }
}
```

After this is done, in your connectionDidFinishLoading method do this check.

```
- (void)connectionDidFinishLoading:(NSURLConnection *)connection {

    NSString *teststr=[[NSString alloc]  initWithData:responseData encoding:NSUTF8StringEncoding];

    NSString *str1234 = [teststr stringByTrimmingCharactersInSet:[NSCharacterSet newlineCharacterSet]];
    NSLog(@"Response is %@ %lul",str1234,(unsigned long)
      [str1234 length]);


    [alert dismissWithClickedButtonIndex:0 animated:YES];

    if (button1.selected)
    {
        [self performSegueWithIdentifier:@"good" sender:self];
    }
    else if (button2.selected)
    {
        [self performSegueWithIdentifier:@"callback" sender:self];
    }
}
```

Hope it helps.

Comment: it works for my but now button get blue when i click on that... is there any way so that it doesn't turn blue.

Comment: Is your button type 'system'? set button type as 'custom'.its probably that

Comment: Please answer my another question which i asked today.